# What is $M_P/M_P^2$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

In Silverman's Arithmetic of EC, page 5, he defines the ideal $M_P$ for a point $P$ of an affine variety $V$ as follows:
$$M_P=\{f\in\overline{K}[V]:f(P)=0\}.$$
That is the functions $f$ in the coordinate ring of $V$ that send $P$ to zero. Then he says that $M_P/M_P^2$ is a finite dimensional $\overline{K}$-vector space and $\dim{V}=\dim_\overline{K}M_P/M_P^2$.

What does $M_P/M_P^2$ mean and what does the dimension of it mean?

Comment: @PatrickStewart It's hard to know what kind of answer you are expecting. It would help if you clarify what you already understand and where exactly you need help. Anyway, let me know if you need further help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$M_P$ is a module over $\overline{K}[V]$ and therefore also a module over $\overline{K}$. Since $\overline{K}$ is a field this means $M_P$ is a vector space over $\overline{K}$. $M_P^2$ is the collection of finite sums of products of elements contained in $M_P$, i.e. $M^2_P=\{\sum f\cdot g|f,g\in M_P\}$ and $M_P/M^2_P$ finally is just the quotient module and in this case a vector space over $\overline{K}$ which happens to have finite dimension.